# How to fix this regex so that it returns only punctuation and words containing punctuation?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that returns words with punctuation, punctuation and words that do not contain punctuation.

```
class String

     def words_and_punctuation
        scan(/[\w'-]+|[[:punct:]]+/)
      end

     def punctuation?
       scan(/\s?[[:punct:]]/).present? 
     end
end
```

I would like to improve so that it returns only punctuation or words that contain punctuation.

Currently I use it like this:

```
text.words_and_punctuation.select(&:punctuation?)
```

string = "The man's hat is really, very nice."

```
string.words_and_punctuation

=> ["The", "man's", "hat", ",", "was", "very", "nice", "."]

string.words_and_punctuation.select(&:punctuation?)

=> ["man's", ",", "."]
```

I would like to not have to use the select and match the correct elements using a regex.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For clarity can you give example of input string and the desired output?

Comment: FYI: it’s 2018 and many use [normal apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe), not the typewriter quote.

Comment: If the intention of the text is to be semantically correct (as if you want a computer to be able to parse the semantics of the text), then you should pay close attention to Unicode's definition of the characters. U+0027 https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66809/what-s-the-right-character-for-an-apostrophe

Comment: What's your take on `It was fine 'til he forgot.` and `girls' dresses`? Are they in the category *words with punctuation* or *punctuation*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my requirements were a bit more involved than at the time that I posted.

I would need to match partially hyphenated words (e.g. "-fast") as well as just 's and even "pay-as-you-go".

So I found the following regex to work.

```
regex = /\w*['-]\w*[-]*\w*[-]*\w*|[[:punct:]]+/

string = "The man, had a big-cat that his Sister's aunt gave him and was -fast 's very-very-big-cat.!!"
```

The sentence does not make much sense but includes some good examples of the words with punctuation and punctuation I need to match.

string.scan(regex)

```
=> [",", "big-cat", "Sister's", "-fast", "'s", "very-very-big-cat", ".!!"]
```

There may be ways to improve the way the regex is written but it's the best I can do that gets the results I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
"The man's hat is really, very nice.".
  scan /\w+[[:punct:]]\w+|[[:punct:]](?=\s|\z)/
#⇒ ["man's", ",", "."]
```

Would probably suffice your needs. This is quite inaccurate, though, since it matches typos like “foo!bar,” but it should be enough for this particular task.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
 /[a-zA-z]+['-][a-z]+|[[:punct:]]/
```

I tried it on a few sentences:

```
2.4.1 :056 > r = Regexp.new /[a-zA-z]+['-][a-z]+|[[:punct:]]/
=> /[a-zA-z]+['-][mst]|[[:punct:]]/
2.4.1 :057 > "The man's hat was, very nice".scan(r)
=> ["man's", ","]
2.4.1 :058 > "The man's hat was, very nice.".scan(r)
=> ["man's", ",", "."]
2.4.1 :059 > "The man's hat was, very nice. who. . would have thougt so?".scan(r)
=> ["man's", ",", ".", ".", ".", "?"]
```

The way it works is, only a couple kinds of punctuation occur inside standard English words--hyphens and apostrophes. So the first part of the regex, before the pipe character, looks for those words, and the second half catches everything else.

Comment: I just realized that I may have hyphenated words such as -fast that I need to catch as well.

Comment: You mean, "I wish I were -fast", like that?

Comment: Yes. The app works with edits of text not the entire text. Some edits look like that.

Comment: ok change that regex to
    /[a-zA-z]*['-][a-z]*|[[:punct:]]/

Answer (score 0):

The common requirement is the presence of punctuation, so make that mandatory:

```
def words_and_punctuation
    scan(/(?:[[:punct:]]|[\w'-])*[[:punct:]]+(?:[[:punct:]]|[\w'-])*/)
end
```

In more typical regex, we might write this pattern as:

```
[&$#^@.A-Za-z0-9'-]*[&$#^@.]+[&$#^@.A-Za-z0-9'-]*
```

In other words, this just says to match one or more punctuation characters optionally surrounded by word characters or more punctuation.  This pattern would not match a word with no punctuation though.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I edited my answer to give more details and an example to show more of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @chell I'm not a Ruby person, so this is probably where I stop.  Did you try my pattern?  It should work (I think).

Comment: I tried it but it does not seem to work as per my requirements.  I used the string="The man's hat was, very nice." => ["man's", "was,", "nice."].

Comment: `["man's", "was,", "nice."]` <-- is this my output or what you expect?  If the latter, then what does my code give you?

Comment: You're trying to exclude apostrophe from being treated as punctuation, yet `[[:punct:]]` most likely includes it.  You may try the second pattern I gave.